# How to maximize this function of X,Y?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, optimization

I have 2 input $X$ and $Y$ which are both positive integers.
I have to maximize this function

> Let $A=\min(Y/4,X/2)$ , $B=\min(W/2,Y/2)$, $C=\max(A,B)$, and $D=\max(X-W,Y)$.
>
> Then
>   $$
> f(X,Y)=\max_{0\leq W\leq X} C\cdot C\cdot D
> $$

How can this problem be solved? Is it possible to determine whether this function will have a single global maximum or not?

Comment: W can vary from 0 to X .

Comment: @julien:W varies from 0 to X .

Comment: @julien:Real values.

Comment: So is my edit correct?

Answer (score 1):

The easy part is this: If $Y\ge 2X$, then $A=X/2$, $B=W/2$, $C=B=W/2$, $D=X-W$, hence $$f(X,Y)=\max_{0\le W\le X} \frac{W^2(X-W)}4=\left.\frac{W^2(X-W)}4\right|_{W=\frac23X}=\frac{X^3}{27}.$$
But if $X\le Y<2X$, you should try to find
$$ f(X,Y)=\max\left\{\max_{0\le W\le Y/2}C^2D, \max_{Y/2< W\le X}C^2D\right\}$$
and the case $Y<X$ need still a bit more consideration.

Comment: is the function f(X,Y)monotonically increasing /decreasing for  X<=Y<2X